# Android Build Failed, strings/google_app_id duplicate resources error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-services, ionic4

I am working on ionic 4. When I run this command in cmd:

```
ionic Cordova build android
```

It gives me a duplicate resource error. I am using firebase and google services.json plugins in my project.

I have tried to remove google_app_id and google_api_key from Andriod.xml file but no change. The same error is displaying again and again. Here is the view of the android.xml file.

Android.xml File

```
 "res/values/strings.xml": {
        "parents": {
          "/resources": [ 
              // removed google_app_id & google_api_key
]
        }
      }
    }
```

Strings.xml File:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">UrbanX Driver</string>
    <string name="launcher_name">@string/app_name</string>
    <string name="activity_name">@string/launcher_name</string>
    <string name="google_app_id">@string/google_app_id</string>
    <string name="google_api_key">@string/google_api_key</string>
</resources>
```

Config.xml File:

```
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin **cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release**:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
```

check this link for reason:

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase#google-play-services

Comment: Thank your for reply. I have tried your solution but now i am facing another error. Firebase Versions are not matching. I am using angularFire2 library for firebase.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [string/google_app_id] C:\Users\hasee\Desktop\ionic\Driver\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml      [string/google_app_id] C:\Users\hasee\Desktop\ionic\Driver\platforms\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/google_api_key] C:\Users\hasee\Desktop\ionic\Driver\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml     [string/google_api_key]